# scrapy doesn't return text I'm looking for

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Total newbie and sorry in advance if I should not post this here... but here we go.
Just wanted to try something new and to try and **scrape** title of product and prices from this website. Need some help on why I'm getting multiple title name and why can't I get the price to work for me.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


    class SpidervenderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'spidervender'
        allowed_domains = ['www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/306165/red-bull-energy-drink']
        start_urls = ['https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/306165/red-bull-energy-drink']
    
        def parse(self, response):
    
            redbulls = response.xpath('//div')
    
            for redbull in redbulls:
                title = redbull.xpath('.//h1[@class="shelfProductTile-title heading3"]/text()').extract_first()
                price = redbull.xpath('.//shared-price/div/span[@class="price-dollars"]').extract_first()
                if title is not None:
                    print(title)
                print(price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get multiple titles because you put in a for-loop. I tried extracting the price and I got errors as well. As a tip, its better to use a yield statement. Extracting the price would be a bit more complicated. The 11 and the 25 cents are in different classes so you have to scrape them separately.

[Redbull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FarDF.jpg)

Comment: Thanks mate! This definitely helped as I didn't realize I placed for-loop. And yes just switched to yield statement